# Maximum data length of all columns in a table-Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table named : "userdetails" which contains columns "username" and "placename". The data as below:

```
Username                        placename
Testuser1                       India-chennai
Testuser2                       India-delhi
Testuser3                       UK-London
```

Now, I would like to know the maximum datalength of the both columns. Like below

```
username                       placename
 9                             13 - which (India-chennai)
```

Is there any possible to identify the same. I have tried the below query but it does not produce the desired output:

```
select data_type, data_length 
  from user_tab_columns
 where table_name = 'userdetails'
   and column_name in ('Username', 'placename');
```

Comment: max size of the column or max existing data value of those column?

Comment: @EzLo: I voted for reopening as Udaya wants to know **which** value is the longest, f.i. "India-chennai". The other question marked in "duplicate" shows only the length, f.i. "13".

Comment: Yes.. corect Ezlo.. Thanks....

Comment: I cannot add an answer until the question is reopened, so therefore the hint as comment: For a quick answer in SQL Developer, I'll just `SELECT place_name FROM userdetails ORDER BY lenght(place_name) DESC` and look at the top results.

Comment: how do i reopen the question

Comment: I believe you can't until your reputation is 3000+. You could ask a new question where you clarify that you want not only the length, but also the content of the longest item. If you do so, it would be good to have a quick look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 2):

If you want max data value of the existing data then try below query

```
Select max(length(Username)) as max_username, max(length(placename)) as max_placename
from userdetails
```

Comment: Yes. I have got the answer.. thanks.